# Selenium not able to recognize the object on a popover

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

[image: popover on a iframe window]

Hi all can someone help me why I am not able to select the "Remove from Account" button. If you look at the screenshot selenium successfully clicks on the star sign where a popover is displayed. I then want selenium to click on the remove from account button but it does not work. Any help is appreciated

This is my code:

```
public void clickSpecialPricingRemoveFromAccount(){
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='singleProductTR']/td[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1])")).click();
}
```

The error message that I get back is:

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //*[@id='singleProductTR']/td[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1]) is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
>   InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id='singleProductTR']/td[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1]) because of the following error:
>   SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
>   Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
>   Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
>   System info: host: 'wdhl843a4bd282a8.corp.intuit.net', ip: '172.17.205.71', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=46.0.1, platform=MAC, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
>   Session ID: 6ef87e2b-beae-424c-9fdf-a3728e4995c4
>   *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id='singleProductTR']/td[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1])}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //[@id='singleProductTR']/td[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1]) is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement

Your provided `xpath` looks syntactically incorrect, it should be :-

```
//*[@id='singleProductTR']/td[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1]
```

You have appended `)` with this `xpath` at the end which shouldn't be there.

But you can use more specific `xpath` instead which would be more stable using `innerText` as below :-

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[text() = 'Remove from Account']").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have only one element with popup-header-cpq. You could simply use css selector:

webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.popup-header-cpq button:first-of-type")).click().

Answer (score 0):

Using the css, an efficient selector would be:

```css
button[onclick*='displayPopoverRemoveEntitlement']
```